# regex unknown error msvcrt!_iob under Qt 4.8 built with latest mingw-builds

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have just built Qt 4.8 with the latest mingw-builds, all my c++ projects works fine, except this line: `regex r("\\d+");`
which works fine at my friend PC with Qt 4.8 but debugged with msvc2010.
If I'm writing this line: `regex r;`
it's doesnt break on this line, but then any thing I'm trying to do with "r" leading to the same unknown error result.

If I look at Qt debug window on the table of (Level,Function,File,Line), I can see:

```
0   msvcrt!abort    C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll      0x7fefd9c537c   
1   libstdc++-6!_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv    C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll        0x6fc5cc82  
2   msvcrt!_iob C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll      0x7fefda12ae0   
3   ??          0x22f530    
4   ??          0x22f530    
5   ??          0x22f962e8  
6   msvcrt!__pioinfo    C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll      0x7fefd993fc0   
7   ??          0x22f5f0    
8   ??          0xffffffff  
9   ??          0x22e37900  
10  ??          0x1 
11  ??          0x22f6d8    
12  ??          0x22ea9610  
13  libstdc++-6!__dynamic_cast  C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll        0x6fce1190  
14  ??          0x22f5b0    
15  libstdc++-6!_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv    C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll        0x6fc5cc2e  
16  ??          0x22a8c0    
17  ??          0x22f750    
18  ??          0x22f669e0  
19  ??          0x202   
20  ??
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::regex` is part of c++11 standard library.

Mingw must [haven't included](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) support of regular expressions yet, while VS 2010 supports them.

However, you can use [`QRegExp`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QRegExp.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure mingw-builds project have includes most of the c++11, but apparently not. I changed my code to work with QRegExp, and it's even cleaner and simple then before.